# What determines the actual instantiated values of the quantum numbers for a given atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry

The following image depicts various n, m, l values for a given hydrogen atom. I understand that these values are obtained by solving the Schrödinger equation.

If you figuratively gave me a hydrogen atom as a gift, how would I determine which n, m, l values actually apply for the probability density function for its electron?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no particular reason why you should expect the hydrogen atom to be in one of the listed states. Those states are one particular choice of *basis* states for the hydrogen atom, meaning that in general the atom may be in any superposition thereof. This particular set of basis states consists of simultaneous eigenstates of $H$, $L^2$, and $L_z$. So if you have a way to measure the energy of the electron, then you can determine the quantum number $n$. If you have a way to measure the total angular momentum of the electron, then you can determine $\ell$. Finally, if you have a way to measure the angular momentum around the z-axis, then you can determine $m$.

As for why the atom got to be a particular state in the first place (which, again, may not be one of the basis states listed), it is determined by the process that created the atom and any interactions it may have been subject to since it was created, and the laws of quantum electrodynamics.

Answer (score 3):

Your hydrogen atom will either be in the ground state or it will go into the ground state if you wait a bit - the excited states that you can reach from the ground state are all unstable and will decay back to the ground state.

When it decays to the ground state it will emit light of a particular frequency that you can then use to determine what state it was initially in by comparing it against hydrogen's [spectral series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series). In order to determine $l$ and $m$ you need to put the atom into a magnetic field first so you can observe different frequencies for different $l,m$ due to the [Zeeman effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_effect).